# Determining whether SPARQL query inserted anything

Tags: sparql, rdf

Say I have an update form such as:

```sql
INSERT DATA {
# ... data
}
WHERE {
  FILTER EXISTS { 
# ... condition
  }
}
```

which may or may not insert data depending on whether the `FILTER` condition holds. As far as I can tell, the SPARQL 1.1 update standard makes no recommendations about the response that a SPARQL engine must return after successfully running this query. In other words, there is no way to tell whether data was inserted or not.

Of course, one could subsequently run a `SELECT` query to whether rows have been inserted/changed, but this second query would not run as part of the same transaction as the `INSERT`, so false positives and negatives can be expected.

Am I missing something here? Is there some way, aside from vendor-specific solutions, to determine whether filter conditions matched or not? This seems like a pretty significant limitation.

The only hack I can think of is generating, with every insert, a triple marked with a unique UUID, which gets added to the graph provided that the `FILTER` condition holds. Then a subsequent `SELECT` for this UUID would determine conclusively whether the `INSERT` ran or not.

Comment: that update statement should be rejected and raise an error - other than that, there is nothing beyond 200 OK HTTP status code for a successful request (via HTTP). What you want, i.e. get any number of triples inserted/deleted/modified as far as I know is not in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT DATA { } WHERE { }` isn't legal syntax.

There is `INSERT DATA { }` (for plain data no variables) or `INSERT { } WHERE { }` for a template and binding variables.

- `INSERT DATA` :: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#insertData
- `INSERT {} WHERE {}`  :: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#insert